# Una parola per 'persona che si lamenta del suo gruppo di appartenenza ma si guarda bene dal lasciarlo'

Tags: single-words

Esiste una parola per definire una "persona che si lamenta del suo gruppo di appartenenza ma si guarda bene dal lasciarlo"?

In questi giorni, fra colleghi e conoscenti, sento dire, per significare quanto sopra, "sei un civati", ma non trovo questa parola neanche fra i neologismi della settimana del Traccani.

Answer (score 2):

I tuoi colleghi si riferiscono a [Pippo Civati](http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Civati), un giovane politico del PD che, nonostante le continue critiche al suo partito, rimane all'interno dello stesso. Una persona con questo tipo di comportamento può essere definita come [incoerente](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/I/incoerente.shtml) ma si potrebbero usare altri aggettivi come indecisa od  opportunista, dipende dalle motivazioni che generano questo comportamento.

Comment: Non vedo dove starebbe l'incoerenza. Uno può benissimo far parte di un qualche gruppo/organizzazione e avere, anche molte, critiche sullo stesso... ma magari ne ha molte di più verso altri gruppi/organizzazioni e dunque è naturale per lui "rimanere lì". E comunque un gruppo dove questo non può avvenire è una dittatura (tipo quella di Grillo in questo momento).

Comment: E' una questione di punti di vista... specialmente quando si parla di politica. Comunque ho detto 'può essere definita come incoerente' non ' deve essere definita come incoerente'.